# How to add mime type "cache-manifest" to Jekyll?

Tags: github, web-applications, jekyll, html5-appcache

The Jekyll site is hosted in GitHub and I want to add `AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache` to .htaccess. I searched and couldn't find anything. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to add an `.htaccess` to GH Pages, as stated [here](https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/):

> For the security of our users, GitHub Pages does not support customer
>   server configuration files such as `.htaccess` or `.conf`.

You will need a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the default mime types, but github pages have a VERY long list of mappings.  Including the one you want.

See https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/10a73596d94c3138eba1a330b52864efecf08a05/lib/jekyll/mime.types#L822
and
https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db/blob/66588fec459c0d61cec5c69cfd161b139f75cf7d/db.json#L6232